# Append HTML Symbol with a TextNode

Tags: jquery, html, append, symbols

I am ultimately trying to add a HTML symbol along with some text into an existing `<span></span>`.

The code I have is:

```
 var someText4 = "Watch Videos";
 $('#nav-item5').append(document.createTextNode(someText4));
```

But I need the `&#153;` (™) symbol at the end of Watch Videos.

Comment: So... you want to add that text to the end of it? such as `+ "&#153;"`? or `+ "&trade;"`?

Comment: You should be able to just include the HTML entity in your string: `var someText4 = "Watch Videos &#153;";`

Comment: @KevinB, yes I am looking to add it to the end of the string, but by adding + "&#153;" the end result of the append is Watch Videos&#153; I think I have to create a variable that .html("&#153;") to someText4, but is it possible to .html() to a string?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use .html and .append with a string. Just make sure it's just a string and not a string that contains html, as that could have odd side effects.

Comment: The solution: $('#nav-item5').html("Watch Videos"+"&#153;"); Thanks for the help